# Inserting a row into a table - How to deal with MYSQL Functions?

Tags: php, mysql, binding, pdo

I don't intend to reinvent the wheel, but I wanted to create a simple `insertRow($table, $array)` method in PHP.

The `$array` is an associative array in the form of `columnName => value` of where to insert in the table. I intended to prepare a statement in the form of

```
INSERT INTO `tableName`(`$keys[0], $keys[1], etc`) VALUES (?,?,?)
```

Then bind the values, and execute. However, I don't know how to deal with MYSQL functions (eg. FROM_UNIXTIME). I just learnt that I can't bind the function, it has to be present in the prepared statement.

So, is there a way to deal with MYSQL functions in a way that isn't overly complicated?

Here's my method thus far:

```
public function insertRow($table, $array){

    $columns = count($array);   //number of columns to insert
    $keys = array_keys($array); //names of the columns
    $vals = array_values($array);   //values of corresponding names $array == ($keys => $vals)

    $strCols = '(`'.implode("`,`", $keys).'`)'; //column names in SQL style string (`col1`, `col2`, `col3`, etc)
    $strVals = $this->bindings_string($columns);    //SQL style for binding values (?,?,?,etc.)

    try{
        $query = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO `$table`$strCols VALUES $strVals");

        for($i = 0; $i < $columns; $i++){
            $query->bindValue($i+1, $vals[$i]);         
        }
        $query->execute();
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo '<b>Error: </b>', $e->getMessage();        
    }
}

private function bindings_string($count){
    $strVals = '(';
    for($i = 1; $i < $count; $i++){
        $strVals .= '?,';       
    }
    $strVals .= '?)';   
    return $strVals;
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem with this code? If you're wanting a critique of the code, then that's off topic. try http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @MarcB My code will only work for inserting rows with static values. I'm asking is there a way to insert rows which may/may not have MYSQL functions such as `FROM_UNIXTIME().`

Comment: Wrap the functions around the placeholders, e.g. `UPDATE ... SET somefield=FROM_UNIXTIME(?)`. As you're going to find out very quickly, it is VERY hard to write a universal "build some sql for me" utility set, because SQL can take pretty much any form you like.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - I guess I'll leave this for the pros.